# Wondering why this ethernet wall plug is not working?

Tags: ethernet

I have an ethernet wall socket in one room which is wired to another ethernet wall socket in another room.

Everything appears to be connected up correctly, but it does not appear to be functioning.

Here are photos of the wiring.

## Room 1 Wiring

[image]

## Room 2 Wiring

[image]

## What I have tried

Room 1 has the internet router. An ethernet cable connects the router to the ethernet wall socket.

Room 2 has a laptop. An ethernet cable connects the laptop to the ethernet wall socket.

If I connect the laptop directly to the internet router, it can browse the internet.

If I connect the laptop to a internet router *via said ethernet wall socket*, it does not work.

I have used a multimeter to check that each colored wire is properly seated in its socket. I touched the tip of the probe to the end of the wire, and the tip of the other probe to the two cutters that go through the insulation to the wire underneath.

## Update

It works perfectly now, after following the answer by @Dwayne Reid.

This practical example has helped me understand more about the physics that run our world.

## Update 2016-03-30

9 months on, and it's still working solidly. @Dwayne Reid and @Charles Cowie, thank you again!

## Update 2017-09-23

Over 2 years later, and it's still working brilliantly. @Dwayne Reid and @Charles Cowie, if I could buy you a beer, I would!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see two issues:

1) The wire colors appear to be incorrect.  If you look closely at the bottom right pair of terminals in the 2nd picture, you see that you can use either green plus white *OR* orange plus white for that pair of terminals.

You have both the green and orange wires going to that bottom right pair of terminals - that is wrong.  Pull those wires off the terminals and match up the solid color with the white + striped color on the appropriate pins

2) You are violating the maximum amount of un-twist allowed in the wire pairs.  Ethernet signals are *VERY* fast and passing an undistorted signal relies upon the pair impedance being constant.  When you have large sections of wire that are not twisted, you get impedance discontinuities which leads to signal degradation.

Comment: You are brilliant, and 100% correct! It works perfectly now. I redid the wiring to ensure that solid color matched striped color. I also twisted the wires to within 2 centimeters of the terminal. Thanks!

Comment: Can you also send a diagram on how the att is connected to the fiber optics box in the house and the how that box is connected to the wall box that gets distributed over all the wall sockets. something simple like a single line diagram.

Answer (score 2):

1. Use an ohmmeter or continuity checker to make sure no two wires are shorted to each other when nothing is plugged in.
2. Attach a clip lead to short each pair at one end and check at the other end to make sure you have continuity for each pair.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. This was going to be my next step, as there is no way it would work if either of the tests you suggested had failed.